# Visual Studio 2010 File Open - Say its already open!

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution which has 20 projects. One of them is a website project.

When I try to open a js file in the website project for the first time, it opens fine.

But when I try to open any of those js files, it gives me this error:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
The document 'X:\\....path.js' is already open. Do you want to close it?
---------------------------
Yes   No   
---------------------------
```

I tried to search on forums, internet, MSDN and everywhere, its quiet annoying.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I only have some tips:

- You can use the handle utility of sysinternals.com to find out if and which process is holding the file open. This utility can also close such a handle with violence.
- I guess that X: is a network drive. Is it possible that this file is actually opened from a different computer? It might be in use i.e by a Web-test server?
- Did you try to open this very file with a different program (i.e. notepad) on the same machine, when the project is loaded in VS?

Comment: Thanks for your tips:

1. Its not locked

2. X was just an example, i have it in physical SSD drive

3. in Operating systems, this feature is called 'exclusive opening' and there is no such exclusive opening there, I have fully investigated using those tools.

I am 99% sure its a Visual Studio related issue.

Comment: You open the first first time, it opens fine, then you close it and when you open after 1 second, it gives you that prompt, even then you CANT open the file now, you must exit visual studio and reopen it, load the project, then you'd be able to open.

I am running win 7 ultimate edition 64bit with 8gb ram and raid1+0 built on 10 ssd drives, pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is shown when the same file is open in the same VS instance, but with another editor (you'll see it e.g. when opening a resource file in the code editor when it is already open in the resource file editor). Did you open the file in both cases by double-clicking? Try to play around with the *Open With* command, which allows you to select the VS editor.

The error message is not related to another application holding the file open.

What happens when you confirm closing it? Do you have any Visual Studio extensions or add-ins installed? Try disabling all of them.

Comment: The standard occurrence of the error is when the file is already open. It may also come when a file is already open with 'exclusive' rights by another program. Neither are the conditions here... I have tested the file access open/read/write with external tools to verify that no other program is accessing the file at the time. Its freely available for visual studio even then its showing this error.

Nothing happens when I confirm close or cancel, I just cant open the file in visual studio from there on. The only lame workaround is to close visual studio and reopen!! disabled all ext or addins!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a TypeScript file in VS2013 Premium.

Restarting VS and then the machine didn't prevent the issue. Opening VS in Safemode didn't help. The only solution I found was position my mouse over the 'X' on the document the message box was complaining about (much easier with a trackball than a mouse)  and open the solution with the keyboard, ensuring the pointer was in the right place to close the document as soon as it rendered and before the message box was shown.

UPDATE: A simpler fix is to delete the .suo file. That lets you open the solution with no open files.